# Sinewave riding on sinewave help

Tags: parametric, recursion, curves

Consider this image
[image]

Top one is Cos(t), I know that.
What is the equation for the second one? (sinewave within sinewave)
And how would I get to the third one and then on *n*-amount of recursion?

Mind boggling for me!

Comment: Still trying to figure out the helix problem, huh? :). It's easy to picture what it should be, but I tried earlier today with no big results, and mathematica was not playing nice with the complicated shapes. I suspect you'll need to make serious and careful use of the frenet frame.

Comment: Going deeper and deeper down the helix rabbit hole here...Frenet frame? Ok I'll check it out! If somebody wants to chime in, feel free :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given a parameterized curve $f$, we want to create a new curve $g$ which is the same as $f$, but with some oscillations added. In particular, we want the oscillations in $g$ to always be perpendicular to motion of $f$. So, in vectors, if we let $\hat{f}(t)$ be normal (perpendicular vector) to $f$ at time $t$ we could write:
$$g(t)=f(t)+a\sin(bt)\hat{f}(t)$$
where $a$ is the amplitude of the new wave and $b$ is the frequency - which are parameters you can play with to your heart's content. Note that you could easily define $\hat{f}$ as a 90 degree rotation and normalization (i.e. divide by magnitude) of $f'(t)$, the derivative. And, if you start this process with $f(t)=(t,0)$ - a line - and repeatedly apply the transformation that takes $f$ to $g$, you will get nested waves like this. However, this expression gets ugly very quickly if you want a closed form; for instance, with 2 nested waves for certain parameters that I thought seemed reasonable, one gets the expression

$$\left\{x-\frac{\sin (20 x) \cos (x)}{3 \sqrt{\cos ^2(x)+1}},\sin (x)+\frac{\sin (20 x)}{3 \sqrt{\cos ^2(x)+1}}\right\}$$
This is ugly. You don't want to see the expression for 3 nested waves.

Note that a similar method would work in 3 dimensions, but since the set of vectors normal to a 3D curve two dimensional, it's trickier.

Comment: When you say "Given a parameterized curve F", does that mean F = Cos(t) in this case? So in wolfram I can write   g[t] = Cos[t] + a Sin[b t] * Normalize[Cos[t]] ? If I bump up the B in that equation, I get ripples but they aren't perpendicular to the curve.

Comment: What you want is f[t] = {t,Cos(t)} (in Wolfram-friendly terms) - that is, you specify both x and y coordinates over time (since this doesn't form the graph of a function). The normal to this is Normalize[{Sin(t),1}] (note that f'[t]={1,-Sin[t]} - we switch the coordinates and negate one).